# Unable to replace String with default value

Tags: php, mysql

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    require 'dbconnect.php';
    $conn=new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$dbname);
    $m=$_POST['no2'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Users(no1,no2,Shop_id,Price) VALUES('".$_POST['no1']."','str_replace("+","0",'$m')','".$_POST['Shop_id']."','".$_POST['Price']."')";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(!$result){
        /* check for error, die, etc */
        echo "string";
    }

    $conn->close();
 ?>
```

I want to replace string that is got from `POST($m)` request to a string that does not contain '+' i.e remove '+' from string.

I have tried replacing it with '0' (after all hope), but still not showing what I intent to see

Say `$m=+12345`, I want it to be `$m=12345` when inserting to Database

Pls help me this.i am pretty much newbie to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the post request you can get + in value otherwise in query string you will get SPACE.

An issue in concatenation

```
$m=str_replace("+","0",$_POST['no2']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users(no1,no2,Shop_id,Price) VALUES('".$_POST['no1']."','".$m."','".$_POST['Shop_id']."','".$_POST['Price']."')";
```

Comment: Yep.Works Fine.Thanks.$m=str_replace("+","",$_POST['no2']);

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `$sql = "INSERT INTO Users(no1,no2,Shop_id,Price) VALUES('".$_POST['no1']."','str_replace("+","0",'$m')','".$_POST['Shop_id']."','".$_POST['Price']."')";` with `$sql = "INSERT INTO Users(no1,no2,Shop_id,Price) VALUES('".$_POST['no1']."','".str_replace("+","0",$_POST['no2'])."','".$_POST['Shop_id']."','".$_POST['Price']."')";`. Then check and let me know.

Comment: ".str_replace("+","0",'+123')." --Then i get as 0123

Comment: @AdharshVS Ok, then as per your query this is ok or need anything else?